# Wordpress Builder Plugin Anchor Links Stopped Working

Tags: wordpress, anchor-scroll

Any help on this is very much appreciated. I'm trying to fix these anchor links in wordpress for a client and all of the sudden the anchor links have just stopped working. Nothing has been modified, no additional plugins have been added, they just are not responding anymore for some reason. Its wordpress 4.4.2 and they are using the builder plugin as well. Here is the url of the live site: http://www.franchiseinnovationgroup.com

The weird part is that the #top and #footer anchors work but not the #about, #portfolio, #testimonials, & #contact anchors.

Any help would GREATLY be appreciated!

Thanks,

Brad

Comment: Seems fine to me?  `http://www.franchiseinnovationgroup.com/#testimonials`  I do see a bunch of console errors.  Probably best to fix ALL of those!  I do see you've renamed some content `div id="section-testimonials" ` was that intended?

Comment: `http://www.franchiseinnovationgroup.com/#section-testimonials` seems to work in most browsers.  Looks like `http://www.franchiseinnovationgroup.com/#testimonials` works in Chrome because of some extra code the google browser guys seem to  have added off standard.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. To answer your question about the div's, no that wasn't intended. Is there a fix for this? The previous developer built the site solely using the builder plugin and didn't actually code/hard-code anything.